# Dart - Draggable Image

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get a draggable image in Dart. Though setting the draggable bool of my image doesn't work.

```
image = new ImageElement();
image.src = ImageSourceByName(name);
image.on.load.add((event) {Context.drawImage(image, 10, 10, CARD_SMALL_WIDTH, CARD_SMALL_HEIGHT);});
image.draggable = true;
```

(Note: Context is the 2D context I get from my Canvas.)

The drawing works perfectly, I can see my card, though I can't drag it around. I'm pretty new to Dart, so it might be something obvious, though I can't find any tutorial explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an ImageElement as the source to paint something on your CanvasElement.
Once the pixels are on the canvas(through drawImage()), your image data is not an HTMLElement but, well, pixels :)

The `draggable` attr, however, is an attribute of an HTMLElement.
If you add the image to your document, you'll notice that you can study the behaviour of `draggable`, like this:
`document.body.nodes.add(image);`

If you 'only' want to have draggable images, you can take it from there and maybe look at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html
Otherwise, if you want stuff on a canvas to be draggable, thats a different(more complicated?) story.

Comment: Aha, that explains it. I used to use kineticjs, which had the draggable stuff enabled even for stuff on a canvas, so I thought it worked everywhere, but I guess it was something of kineticjs itself then. So to make it dragable I have to write code for that myself? (assuming I want to use the canvas, which I do, since I'm making a game.)

Comment: Yea, you have to do this 'by feet' for canvas, I guess : )
I'm totally unfamiliar with canvas work, so unfortunately I cant provide further pointers.